# is there a way to put basic banshee controls in the top bar of unity?

Tags: banshee, music, rhythmbox, customization, taskbar

Im looking for a way to put basic controls like pause, play, and skip to the top taskbar (the area which displays the time, battery, mail, titles of pages in chrome...) or some other convenient way to have banshee controls available to me at all times even when in a maximized window.

Comment: those controls are in the volume indicator - is this missing on your desktop?

Comment: oh wow. i spent like an hour looking for this. thanks for pointing this out, i feel so dumb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>converted comment to answer</sub>

Generally, most music/media-player applications such as Banshee supports the Unity-volume indicator:

[image]

From there you have the standard stop-pause-play controls as well as control over your playlists.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use Keyboard Shortcuts and set some of the Sound shortcuts as shown in this screenshot.  [image].

In this example, I have set shortcuts for previous and next tracks (Ctrl+Alt+PgUp, Ctrl+Alt+PgDn).